# How to use nested JSON object data as source for datatable columns?

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I have a local JSON object that is formatted like so:

```
var rosterdata = {
    "homeQBs": ["Ryan Mallet", "Joe Flacco"],
    "homeRBs": ["Bobby Rainey", "Terrance West", "Alex Collins", "Javorius Allen"],
    "homeWRs": ["Mike Wallace", "Chris Matthews", "Jeremy Maclin", "Griff Whalen", "Breshad Perriman"],
    "homeTEs": ["Nick Boyle", "Gavin Escobar", "Maxx Williams", "Benjamin Watson"],
    "awayQBs": ["Matt Moore", "Jay Cutler", "David Fales"],
    "awayRBs": ["Senorise Perry", "Damien Williams", "Kenyan Drake", "Jay Ajayi"],
    "awayWRs": ["Kenny Stills", "Leonte Carroo", "Jakeem Grant", "DeVante Parker", "Jarvis Landry"],
    "awayTEs": ["Anthony Fasano", "MarQueis Gray", "Julius Thomas"]
  }
```

Please note the arrays are not equal in length.

I want to display the data in a table like so:

[see example of how first row should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj94X.png)

I can't figure out how to get the data in each column, and all the nested object examples I've seen are conveniently homogenous sets.

Here's my current try:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var rosterdata = {
    "homeQBs": [],
    "homeRBs": [],
    "homeWRs": [],
    "homeTEs": [],
    "awayQBs": [],
    "awayRBs": [],
    "awayWRs": [],
    "awayTEs": []
  }

  {% for player in match_data.home.players %}
    {% if player.position == 'QB' %}
        rosterdata.homeQBs.push("{{ player.name }}");
        console.log("home QB added:" + '{{player.name}}' );
        console.log(rosterdata);
    {% endif %}
    {% if player.position == 'RB' %}
        rosterdata.homeRBs.push("{{ player.name }}");
    {% endif %}
    {% if player.position == 'WR' %}
        rosterdata.homeWRs.push("{{ player.name }}");
    {% endif %}
    {% if player.position == 'TE' %}
        rosterdata.homeTEs.push("{{ player.name }}");
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% for player in match_data.away.players %}
    {% if player.position == 'QB' %}
        rosterdata.awayQBs.push("{{ player.name }}");
    {% endif %}
    {% if player.position == 'RB' %}
        rosterdata.awayRBs.push("{{ player.name }}");
    {% endif %}
    {% if player.position == 'WR' %}
        rosterdata.awayWRs.push("{{ player.name }}");
    {% endif %}
    {% if player.position == 'TE' %}
        rosterdata.awayTEs.push("{{ player.name }}");
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  $('#teamsroster').DataTable( {
    data: rosterdata,
    columns: [
      { data: "homeQBs[]" },
      { data: "homeRBs" },
      { data: "homeWRs" },
      { data: "homeTEs" },
      { data: "awayQBs" },
      { data: "awayRBs" },
      { data: "awayWRs" },
      { data: "awayTEs" }
    ],
    select: {
        style: 'single',
        items: 'cell'
    },
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    ordering: false,
  } );



} );
//console.log(window.rosterdata);
</script>
```

and the html:

```
<table id="teamsroster" class="table table-bordered w-100" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>QB</th>
            <th>RB</th>
            <th>WR</th>
            <th>TE</th>
            <th>QB</th>
            <th>RB</th>
            <th>WR</th>
            <th>TE</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anshikakaythwas/hxLnezxh/).

```
var rosterdata = {
  "homeQBs": ["Ryan Mallet", "Joe Flacco"],
  "homeRBs": ["Bobby Rainey", "Terrance West", "Alex Collins", "Javorius Allen"],
  "homeWRs": ["Mike Wallace", "Chris Matthews", "Jeremy Maclin", "Griff Whalen", "Breshad Perriman"],
  "homeTEs": ["Nick Boyle", "Gavin Escobar", "Maxx Williams", "Benjamin Watson"],
  "awayQBs": ["Matt Moore", "Jay Cutler", "David Fales"],
  "awayRBs": ["Senorise Perry", "Damien Williams", "Kenyan Drake", "Jay Ajayi"],
  "awayWRs": ["Kenny Stills", "Leonte Carroo", "Jakeem Grant", "DeVante Parker", "Jarvis Landry"],
  "awayTEs": ["Anthony Fasano", "MarQueis Gray", "Julius Thomas"]
};
max = 0;
$.map(rosterdata, function(value, key) {
  $.map(value, function(ele, i) {
    if (i > max)
      max = i;
  });

});

var dataset = [];
for (i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
  var row = {};
  Object.keys(rosterdata).forEach(function(key) {
    if (rosterdata[key][i] != null)
      row[key] = rosterdata[key][i];
  });
  dataset.push(row);
}
```

You can use the dataset created here, as the data source of your datatable.
Hope it helps!